# How to match rows with one or more words in query, but without any words not in query?

Tags: sphinx

I have a table in a MySQL database that has a list of comma separated tags in it.

I want users to be able to enter a list of comma separated tags and then use [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or MySQL to select rows that have *at least one of the tags in the query* but *not any tags the query doesn't have*.

The query can have additional tags that are not in the rows, but the rows should not be matched if they have tags not in the query.

I either want to use Sphinx or MySQL to do the searching.

Here's an example:

```
creatures:
----------------------------
| name |  tags             |
----------------------------
| cat  | wily,hairy        |
| dog  | cute,hairy        |
| fly  | ugly              |
| bear | grumpy,hungry     |
----------------------------
```

Example searches:

```
wily,hairy         <-- should match cat
cute,hairy,happy   <-- should match dog
happy,cute         <-- no match (dog has hairy)
ugly,yuck,gross    <-- should match fly
hairy              <-- no match (dog has cute cat has wily)
grumpy             <-- no match (bear has hungry)
grumpy,hungry      <-- should match bear
wily,grumpy,hungry <-- should match bear
```

Is it possible to do this with Sphinx or MySQL?

To reiterate, the query will be a list of comma separated tags and rows that have *at least one of the entered tags* but *not any tags the query doesn't have* should be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx expression ranker should be able to do this.

```
sphinxQL> SELECT *, WEIGHT() AS w FROM index 
   WHERE MATCH('@tags "cute hairy happy"/1') AND w > 0 
   OPTION ranker=expr('IF(word_count>=tags_len,1,0)');
```

basically you want the number of matched tags never to be less than the number of tags.

Note these just gives all documents a weight of 1, if want to get more elaborate ranking (eg to match other keywords) it gets more complicated.

You need `index_field_lengths` enabled on the index to get the tags_len attribute.

(the same concept is obviouslly possible in mysql.. probably using  FIND_IN_SET to do matching. And either a second column to store the number, or compute the number of tags, using say the REPLACE function)

---

Edit to add, details about multiple fields...

```
sphinxQL> SELECT *, WEIGHT() AS w FROM index 
   WHERE MATCH('@tags "cute hairy happy"/1 @tags2 "one two thee"/1') AND w = 2 
   OPTION ranker=expr('SUM(IF(word_count>=IF(user_weight=2,tags2_len,tags_len),1,0))'), 
    field_weights=(tags=1,tags2=2);
```

The SUM function is run for each field in turn, so need to use the user_weight system to get be able to distinguish which field currently enumerating.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to get a `word_count` for each column instead of the total number of words matched? If I added a `tags2` column  and wanted to replicate the matching behavior (i.e. a set of tags would be passed for each tags column) then using `word_count` would no longer work. In this case, the IF statement would need to be: `IF(tag_word_count>=tags_len AND tag2_word_count>=tags2_len,1,0)`

Comment: Actually `word_count` is field specific. It just works because one field. With multiple fields need to get more creative, one major issue, is the ranking formular doesnt know the name of the current field. But does have the user_weight that is field specific. Will update the answer.