# Return rows where words match in two columns OR in match in one column and the other column is empty?

Tags: sphinx

This is a follow-up to [another question I recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767577/how-to-match-rows-with-one-or-more-words-in-query-but-without-any-words-not-in).

I currently have a SphinxQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_index
WHERE MATCH(\'@field1 "a few words"/1 @field2 "more text here"/1\')
```

However, I would still like it to match rows in the case where one of the fields in the row is empty.

For example, let's say the following rows exist in the database:

```
field1        | field2
-----------------------
words in here | text in here
              | text in here
```

The above query would match the first row, but it would not match the second row because the quorum operator specifies that there has to be one or more matches for each field.

Is what I'm asking possible?

The actual query I'm trying to make this work with was provided in [Barry Hunter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28768182/1101095) to my previous question:

```
sphinxQL> SELECT *, WEIGHT() AS w FROM index 
   WHERE MATCH('@tags "cute hairy happy"/1 @tags2 "one two thee"/1') AND w = 2 
   OPTION ranker=expr('SUM(IF(word_count>=IF(user_weight=2,tags2_len,tags_len),1,0))'), 
    field_weights=(tags=1,tags2=2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is sphinx doesn't index "empty" so you can't search for it. (well actually the `field_len` attribute will be zero. But it can be hard to combine attribute filter with MATCH())

... so arrange for empty to be something to index

```
sql_query = SELECT id,...,IF(tags='','_empty_',tags) AS tags FROM ...
```

Then modify the query. As it happens your quorum search is easy!

```
@field1 "a few words _empty_"/1
```

Its just another word. But a more complex query would just have to be OR'ed with the word.

---

Then there is making it work within your complex query. But as luck would have it, its really easy. `_empty_` is just another word. And in the case of the field being empty, one word will match. (ie there are no words in the field, not in the query)

So just add `_empty_` into the two quorums and you done!